# While loop when comparing list never exits

Tags: python

I'm trying to compare list's so that it will play TocTacToe till someone wins how ever when one of the columns, rows, or diagonals(or what ever u want to call them) is filled with 1's or 2's it does exit even though the while loop is only supposed to run while the columns and rows don't equal 1,1,1 or 2,2,2.

My code:

```
import random
import sys
import os
import time
clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
clear()

pWin = [1, 1, 1]
cWin = [2, 2, 2]

bV = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]

squares = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

s1 = squares[0]
s2 = squares[1]
s3 = squares[2]
s4 = squares[3]
s5 = squares[4]
s6 = squares[5]
s7 = squares[6]
s8 = squares[7]
s9 = squares[8]

c1 = [s1,s4,s7]
c2 = [s2,s5,s7]
c3 = [s3,s6,s9]
r1 = [s1,s2,s3]
r2 = [s4,s5,s6]
r3 = [s7,s8,s9]
d1 = [s1,s5,s9]
d2 = [s3,s5,s7]

test = 4

board1 = [bV[0], bV[1], bV[2]]
board2 = [bV[3], bV[4], bV[5]]
board3 = [bV[6], bV[7], bV[8]]

while c1 or c2 or c3 or r1 or r2 or r3 or d1 or d2 != pWin or cWin:

    clear()
    skip = 0
    choiceComplete = 0
    nC = 0

    print(c1)
    print(c2)
    print(c3)
    print(r1)
    print(r2)
    print(r3)
    print(d1)
    print(d2)

    print(pWin)
    print(cWin)

    while nC <= 8:
        if squares[nC] == 1:
            bV[nC] = "X"
            nC = nC + 1
        elif squares[nC] == 2:
            bV[nC] = "O"
            nC = nC + 1
        elif squares[nC] == 0:
            nC = nC + 1

    board1 = [bV[0], bV[1], bV[2]]
    board2 = [bV[3], bV[4], bV[5]]
    board3 = [bV[6], bV[7], bV[8]]

    print(board1)
    print(board2)
    print(board3)


    uChoice = int(raw_input("Your turn, choose a spot: "))
    '''
    uChoice = test
    '''

    cN = uChoice - 1

    if squares[cN] == 0:
        squares[cN] = 1
    elif squares[cN] == 1 or 2:
        print("Sorry, that square has already been chosen.")
        time.sleep(2)
        skip = 1

    if skip == 0:
        while choiceComplete == 0:
            cChoice = random.randrange(1,10)
            gN = cChoice - 1
            if squares[gN] == 0:
                squares[gN] = 2
                choiceComplete = 1
    s1 = squares[0]
    s2 = squares[1]
    s3 = squares[2]
    s4 = squares[3]
    s5 = squares[4]
    s6 = squares[5]
    s7 = squares[6]
    s8 = squares[7]
    s9 = squares[8]

    c1 = [s1,s4,s7]
    c2 = [s2,s5,s7]
    c3 = [s3,s6,s9]
    r1 = [s1,s2,s3]
    r2 = [s4,s5,s6]
    r3 = [s7,s8,s9]
    d1 = [s1,s5,s9]
    d2 = [s3,s5,s7]

'''
    test = test + 1
'''
if c1 or c2 or c3 or r1 or r2 or r3 or d1 or d2 == pWin:
    print("You Won!")



if c1 or c2 or c3 or r1 or r2 or r3 or d1 or d2 == pWin:
    print("You lost!")
```

The part I'm talking about:

```
while c1 or c2 or c3 or r1 or r2 or r3 or d1 or d2 != pWin or cWin:
```

P.S. As you can tell I'm very new to coding, I started 2 days ago, so any constructive criticism on my code is greatly appreciated.

Comment: this doesn't parenthesize the way you think it will. This will loop until `c1` has zero elements, `c2` has zero elements, `c3` has zero elements, `r1` through `r3` have zero elements, `d1` has zero elements, `d2 == pWin`, and `cWin` has zero elements.

Comment: Note that `a or b == c` is not equivalent to `a == c or b == c`. Also, `a == b or c` is not equivalent to `a == b or a == c`. Also, `a or b != c or d` is not equivalent to... Actually, I'm not sure what you intend that to be equivalent to, but it's probably not equivalent to it.

Comment: Ohhhh snap... You should look up `python any()` and also: `python loops`, `python dictionaries`

Comment: There are countless TicTacToe games out there. Find one with a small amount of code and read it line to line and you will learn a lot.